# Why is there a potential difference between VCC and Output pins of A3144 hall sensor?

Tags: voltage, sensor, hall-effect, magnet

When we bring a magnet near the A3144 sensor the PD between output and GND goes to zero but how come does the PD between output and VCC becomes equal to the PD of VCC and GND. Also when the magnet moves away the PD between output and VCC becomes negative. Is there something like subtraction of the PD happening here or there is something else ? I don't know what this phenomenon is called or the laws or logic behind this, but would love to get an answer and explanation.

Comment: what voltage were you expecting to measure between output and Vcc when the output is at 0 V?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the voltages on VCC and PD are referenced to the ground which is 0V reference.

If there is some voltage in reference to 0V on VCC pin, and some voltage in reference to 0V on PD pin, then by simple mathematics, there is some potential difference between PD and VCC.

Simple logic deduction, if you have 5V between VCC and GND, and 1V between PD and GND, there must be 4V between PD and VCC.